# How to fix bootstrap card formatting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put my cards in a row as seen here https://codepen.io/dnorton94/pen/VwZdRzG I would normal use the bootstrap row class but when I do that on my code below it shrinks the card horizontally.

I am using bootstrap 4.3 & JQuery 3.4

I have tried using the col class to increase the width

```
<div id='filters' class='sections'>
      <div class='filter-attributes'>
        <h4>Type</h4>
        <input type='checkbox' name='type' id='skill' value='skill' >Skill</input>
        <input type='checkbox' name='type' id='passion' value='passion' >Passion</input>
        <input type='checkbox' name='type' id='course' value='course' >Course</input>
        <input type='checkbox' name='type' id='job' value='education' >Education</input>
      </div>
      <div class='filter-attributes'>
        <h4>Personality</h4>
        <input type='checkbox' name='personality' id='large' value='istj' >ISTJ</input>
        <input type='checkbox' name='personality' id='small' value='esfj' >ESFJ</input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <br>
        <input type='button' id='none' value='Clear all'></input>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="container">
    <div class='sections'>
            <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3 grid-products" data-type='skill' data-personality='istj'>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card A</h5>
                        <h6 class- "card-personalityType">Subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3 grid-products" data-type='passion' data-personality='istj'>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card Two</h5>
                        <h6 class- "card-personalityType">Subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $products = $('.grid-products'),
      $filters = $("#filters input[type='checkbox']"),
      product_filter = new ProductFilterLevel2($products, $filters);
  product_filter.init();
});

function ProductFilterLevel2(products, filters) {
  var _this = this;

  this.init = function() {
    this.products = products;
    this.filters = filters;
    this.bindEvents();
  };

  this.bindEvents = function() {
    this.filters.click(this.filterGridProducts);
    $('#none').click(this.removeAllFilters);
  };

  this.filterGridProducts = function() {
    //hide all
    _this.products.hide();
    var filteredProducts = _this.products;
    //filter by colour, size, shape etc
    var filterAttributes = $('.filter-attributes'); 
    // for each attribute check the corresponding attribute filters selected
    filterAttributes.each(function(){
      var selectedFilters = $(this).find('input:checked');
      // if selected filter by the attribute
      if (selectedFilters.length) {
        var selectedFiltersValues = [];
        selectedFilters.each(function() {
          var currentFilter = $(this);
          selectedFiltersValues.push("[data-" + currentFilter.attr('name') + "='" + currentFilter.val() + "']");
        });
        filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(selectedFiltersValues.join(','));
      }
    });
      filteredProducts.show();
  };

  this.removeAllFilters = function() {
    _this.filters.prop('checked', false);
    _this.products.show();
  }
}
```

I expect the cards to line up horizontally at the default card width

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing `</div>` for `<div class="container">` in your example. Even if it's there, you would still need `<div class='sections row'>` at the next line for it to work. Finally, your other css classes, like `sections` could be the reason you're not getting the result you want. Could you please add your .css and preferably a fiddle/codepen of your code? Thanks.

Comment: https://codepen.io/dnorton94/pen/OJLBxVX?editors=1010

There is no css

Comment: I made a simple change @SergeyKudriavtsev which fixed it. Thank You

Comment: Looks like I played [a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) second time today :-D Glad that you were able to fix it. Could you please reply to your own question so that the others with similar problem might benefit from the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='sections'>
            <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3 grid-products" data-type='skill' data-personality='istj'>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card A</h5>
                        <h6 class- "card-personalityType">Subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3 grid-products" data-type='passion' data-personality='istj'>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card Two</h5>
                        <h6 class- "card-personalityType">Subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

to

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='sections row'>
            <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3 grid-products" data-type='skill' data-personality='istj'>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card A</h5>
                        <h6 class- "card-personalityType">Subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3 grid-products" data-type='passion' data-personality='istj'>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card Two</h5>
                        <h6 class- "card-personalityType">Subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

No need to add a new div to create a row simply add the class to the second div